# Hospedagem site php

Tags: php, hospedagem

Desenvolvi uma aplicação php e ao hospedar ela, me retorna o seguinte problema.

> Warning: require_once(service/QualificacaoService.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /var/www/html/caipiraimoveis.com.br/web/Model/IndexModel.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'service/QualificacaoService.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/html/caipiraimoveis.com.br/web/Model/IndexModel.php on line 5

Os diretórios acima  estão nos devidos lugar, no localhost funciona, é preciso fazer algo no servidor web? estou utilizando uol host

```
<?php 
 require_once 'viewsmodel/ImovelViewModel.php';
 require_once 'viewsmodel/ConsultaResumidaViewModel.php';

 require_once 'service/QualificacaoService.php';
 require_once 'service/UtilService.php';
 require_once 'service/YouTubeService.php';

 class IndexModel extends PersistModelAbstract {
```

Comment: Ná maquina local uso xammp

Comment: posta a linha 5 do código!!!

Comment: @Tiago Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Você pode [edit] sua pergunta para fornecer informações adicionais, como seu comentário do xammp. Leia mais em [ask] para melhorar sua pergunta.

Comment: Se o host for linux, verifique o nome dos arquivos/pastas pois ele diferencia maiusculas de minusculas.

Comment: <?php

require_once 'viewsmodel/ImovelViewModel.php';
require_once 'viewsmodel/ConsultaResumidaViewModel.php';
require_once 'service/QualificacaoService.php';
require_once 'service/UtilService.php';
require_once 'service/YouTubeService.php';


class IndexModel extends PersistModelAbstract
{

Linha é require_once 'service/QualificacaoService.php';

Comment: @perdeu acho que vc acertou meu problema, sou novo em php, e estou usando Windows para programar, e Linux para Hospedar...

Fiz da Forma que vc falou e deu certo deu erro em outro arquivo, mesmo erro, vou refatorar todo meu projeto...

Comment: Ou... em vez de refatorar você pode utilizar um autoload e nunca mais passará por esse problema!

Comment: Tiago, o código aqui nos comentários é difícil de ler. Por favor, [**edite**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/30144/edit) a pergunta pra incluir esses detalhes.

Comment: @Premiere acredito que ele terá o mesmo problema, mesmo usando autoload.

Comment: @gmsantos Pelo comentário dele mesmo, o problema já está resolvido, apenas indiquei o autoload para melhorar o código dele evitando incluir arquivo por aquivo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provavelmente é problema com sistema de arquivo, em um servidor linux o sistema de arquivo é case sensitive no windows não. Verifique se o nome e o caminho do arquivo estão exatamente igual.

Answer (score 0):

Esses diretórios estão fora do diretório de acesso web? Experimente usar no inicio do script

```
<?php 
  set_include_path(/var/www/html/viewsmodel/);
   set_include_path(/var/www/html/service/);

 require_once 'ImovelViewModel.php';
 require_once 'ConsultaResumidaViewModel.php';

 require_once 'QualificacaoService.php';
 require_once 'UtilService.php';
 require_once 'YouTubeService.php';
```

Parto do principio que os caminhos no set_include_path estão corretos

Answer (score -2):

Eu tive um problema similar e tive que entrar em contato com o servidor para dar certas permissões que não podia configurar pelo painel de controle. Mas pelo que sei, tu deve criar o mesmo banco lá no servidor com o mesmo nome e com as mesmas tabelas e campos. tudo igualzinho.